# Android: Uploading image on server with php

Tags: php, android, image, upload

Always upload image test.jpg with 0KB on the server!

Here is the picture:

[image]

So you can see what am i getting on the server.

I would appreciate any help or suggesting and i hope i will solve the problem..

Android code:

```
     public class Main extends Activity {

InputStream inputStream;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);   
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
    byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://server/uploader2.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Response " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
          Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
}

public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{

     String res = "";
     StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
     inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
     int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..
     Toast.makeText(this, "contentLength : " + contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     if (contentLength < 0){
     }
     else{
            byte[] data = new byte[512];
            int len = 0;
            try
            {
                while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                {
                    buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer…..
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try
            {
                inputStream.close(); // closing the stream…..
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            res = buffer.toString();     // converting stringbuffer to string…..

            Toast.makeText(this, "Result : " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //System.out.println("Response => " +  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
     }
     return res;


}}
```

and php code... (uploader2.php)

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: image/jpg; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';
echo "<img src=test.jpg>";
?>
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

doFileUpload Function :

```
private void doFileUpload(){
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null; 
    String exsistingFileName = "/sdcard/six.3gp";
    // Is this the place are you doing something wrong.
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    String urlString = "http://192.168.1.5/upload.php";
    try
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","Inside second Method");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName) );
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","Headers are written");
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            tv.append(inputLine);
        // close streams
        Log.e("MediaPlayer","File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }

    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
        String str;            
        while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Log.e("MediaPlayer","Server Response"+str);
        }
        /*while((str = inStream.readLine()) !=null ){

        }*/
        inStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioex){
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
}
```

upload.php

```
<?php

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], "./upload/".$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("chat");


if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']))
{
    $a = $_REQUEST['msg'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO  upload(image)VALUES('$a')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: i'm assuming `tv.append(inputline);` is a text view but what are you using it for?

Comment: You would want to do this using AsyncTask off course.