# Image posting on server from android

Tags: php, android

i am developing an application where i have to send the photos to the php server and for that i have tried the following code

```
public class UploadImage extends Activity {

    Uri currImageURI;
    String image_name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button upload_btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.upload);
        upload_btn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // To open up a gallery browser
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
            }
        });
        HttpUploader uploader = new HttpUploader();
        try {
            image_name = uploader.execute(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI)).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                // currImageURI is the global variable I’m using to hold the content:
                currImageURI = data.getData();
                System.out.println("Current image Path is ----->" + getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));
                TextView tv_path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv_path.setText(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));
            }
        }
    }

    // Convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

// Uploader class

```
class HttpUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String outPut = null;
        for (String sdPath : path) {
            Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdPath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // Resize the image
            double width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
            double height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
            double ratio = 400/width;
            int newheight = (int)(ratio*height);
            System.out.println("----width" + width);
            System.out.println("----height" + height);
            bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, 400, newheight, true);

            // Here you can define .PNG as well
            bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, bao);
            byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
            System.out.println("uploading image now ---" + ba1);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", ba1));

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.aamirarif.com/organizer_json/mobile/test/UploadToServer.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                // print response
                outPut = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.i("GET RESPONSE---", outPut);
                //is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("log_tag ******", "good connection");
                bitmapOrg.recycle();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag ******", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        return outPut;
    }
}
```

but in this code i got the following exception 
1

```
0-14 02:59:59.808: W/dalvikvm(2670): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testing.imageposting/com.testing.imageposting.UploadImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1144)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:398)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:357)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at com.testing.imageposting.UploadImage.getRealPathFromURI(UploadImage.java:78)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at com.testing.imageposting.UploadImage.onCreate(UploadImage.java:54)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-14 02:59:59.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2670):     ... 11 more
```

as i am posting first time image from android to php server so its getting bit complicated for me to handle

Comment: What is in this Line: com.testing.imageposting.UploadImage.getRealPathFromURI(UploadImage.java:78)

Comment: @A.S. here it is      Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);

Comment: i have resolved that now i am getting this

10-14 03:21:37.397: I/GET RESPONSE—-(2973): <b>Warning</b>:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in <b>D:\Hosting\4270676\html\organizer_json\mobile\test\UploadToServer.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />

Comment: Have you provided permission in your manifest to read external storage? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: Now its a failure in your php file in line 19

Comment: @WaleedAhmed There is problem in your webservice so please check out.

Comment: @GrIsHu yeah i get it but although its working but i don't like the way its doing do you know any other way that is better than this

Comment: Check out similar post which might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789703/android-uploading-image-on-server-with-php

Comment: @GrIsHu their code and mine is different i want to get the name after uploading the image