# android image upload to server from url is not working when request from android and working when request from postman

Tags: php, android, image, watermark

It's fine working when I request from postman but when using android request not working "imagejpeg($new_canvas, $destination_folder.'/'.$image_name , 90)" means photo are not upload to server folder ,rest all are working fine

**Android Code:**

```
class LoadAlllist extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllPhoto.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imagepath", uploadimagepath));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profileid", docid));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://example.in/updateDocImage.php",
                "POST", params);

        try
        {
            status =json.getString("status");
            msg=json.getString("message");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**Php code:**

```
<?php
    require_once('../classes/clinic.php');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    $res= array();
    $res1= array();
    $profileid=$_REQUEST['profileid'];
    $imagepath=$_REQUEST['imagepath'];    

    $max_size = 8000; //max image size in Pixels
    $destination_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'img/profile_thumbnail';
    $watermark_png_file = 'http://doctorstay.in/img/php/watermark.png'; //watermark png file
    $imageURL = $imagepath;
    $url_arr = explode ('/', $imageURL);
    $ct = count($url_arr);
    $name = $url_arr[$ct-1];
    $name_div = explode('.', $name);
    $image_name= $name;
    $typeInt = exif_imagetype($imageURL);
    switch($typeInt) {
      case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $image_resource =  imagecreatefromgif($imageURL);
        break;
      case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $image_resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageURL);
        break;
      case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $image_resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageURL);
        break;
      case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $image_resource =  imagecreatefrompng($imageURL);
        break;
      default: 
       $image_resource = false;
    }

    if($image_resource)
    {
        //Copy and resize part of an image with resampling
        list($img_width, $img_height) = getimagesize($imageURL);

        //Construct a proportional size of new image
        $image_scale        = min($max_size / $img_width, $max_size / $img_height); 
    /*  $new_image_width    = ceil($image_scale * $img_width/2);
        $new_image_height   = ceil($image_scale * $img_height/2);*/
        $new_image_width    = 400;
        $new_image_height   = 268;
        $new_canvas         = imagecreatetruecolor($new_image_width , $new_image_height);

        if(imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $image_resource , 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_image_width, $new_image_height, $img_width, $img_height))
        {

            if(!is_dir($destination_folder)){ 
                mkdir($destination_folder);//create dir if it doesn't exist
            }

            //center watermark
            $watermark_left = ($new_image_width/2)-(300/2); //watermark left
            $watermark_bottom = ($new_image_height/2)-(100/2); //watermark bottom

            $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark_png_file); //watermark image
            imagecopy($new_canvas, $watermark, $watermark_left, $watermark_bottom, 0, 0, 300, 100); //merge image
            if(imagejpeg($new_canvas, $destination_folder.'/'.$image_name , 90)) {
              //  echo "success";
            } else{
               // echo "fail";
            }
            imagedestroy($new_canvas); 
            imagedestroy($image_resource);
            //die();
        }
    }       

    $result=clinic::updateDocImage($imagepath,$profileid);   

    if( isset($result))
    {
        $res["status"]="success";
        $res["message"]="";         
    }
    else
    {
        $res["status"]="failed";
        $res["message"]="No record inserted.";
    }

    echo json_encode($res);   
?>
```

Comment: Check this tutorial, it might be helpful
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Uploading image on server with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789703/android-uploading-image-on-server-with-php)